# Python: ctypes how to convert c_char_Array into c_char_p

Tags: python, ctypes

The function `create_string_buffer(b"foo", 3)` returns a type `c_char_Array_3`. Trying to pass this in where `c_char_p` is expected blows up with `TypeError: incompatible types, c_char_Array_3 instance instead of c_char_p instance`. How do I pass the output of `create_string_buffer` into a field that expects `c_char_p`?

I think this person had the same question: https://ctypes-users.narkive.com/620LJv10/why-doesn-t-c-char-array-get-coerced-on-assignment-to-a-pointer

However, it's unclear to me what the answer was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* pass a `create_string_buffer` object to a function with a `c_char_p` as an `.argtypes` parameter, but not when it is a member of a structure.  `cast` can work around it.  This was mentioned in the link you provided in the question.

```
from ctypes import *

class foo(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('bar',c_char_p)]

s = create_string_buffer(b'test')

f = foo()
f.bar = cast(s,c_char_p)
print(f.bar)
s[0] = b'q'
print(f.bar)
```

Output:

```
b'test'
b'qest'
```